# How to stop DjangoJSONEncoder from truncating microseconds datetime objects?

Tags: json, django, datetime

I have a dictionary with a datetime object inside it and when I try to json dump it, Django truncates the microseconds:

```
> dikt
{'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 22, 11, 36, 25, 763835, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Africa/Nairobi' EAT+3:00:00 STD>)}
> json.dumps(dikt, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
'{"date": "2020-06-22T11:36:25.763+03:00"}'
```

How can I preserve all the 6 microsecond digits?

Comment: truncating the microseconds to milliseconds seems hard-coded, see [src](https://github.com/django/django/blob/258c88a913fe1e7704cdb6f61c6ceb7493f6092a/django/core/serializers/json.py#L77)

Comment: `DjangoJSONEncoder` truncates microseconds to full miliseconds to meet up with [ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

Answer (score 0):

`DjangoJsonEncoder` support ECMA-262 specification.

You can easily overcome this by introducing your custom encoder.

```
class MyCustomEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            r = obj.isoformat()
            if r.endswith('+00:00'):
                r = r[:-6] + 'Z'
            return r
        return super(MyCustomEncoder, self).default(obj)



dateime_object = datetime.datetime.now()
print(dateime_object)
print(json.dumps(dateime_object, cls=MyCustomEncoder))

>>> 2020-06-22 11:54:29.127120
>>> "2020-06-22T11:54:29.127120"
```